# Padding or other reason code fails to fit, when placing variable at absolute address {C, Keil, ARM}

Tags: c, arm, memory-address, keil

Trying to figure out why keil is failing to link program with variable placed at absolute address. If same program is being compiled without that variable being placed at absolute address - all is OK.

Failing to link:

```
const uint16_t CRC __attribute__((section(".ARM.__at_0x1FDFC"))) = 0xAE20;
```

> Error: L6985E: Unable to automatically place AT section main.o(.ARM.__at_0x1FDFC) with required base address 0x0001fdfc. Please manually place in the scatter file using the --no_autoat option.

All same, just CRC placed not in absolute address:

```
const uint16_t CRC /*__attribute__((section(".ARM.__at_0x1FDFC")))*/ = 0xAE20;
```

> Program Size: Code=116924 RO-data=11352 RW-data=1536 ZI-data=14808

Moving absolute address a bit further:

```
const uint16_t CRC __attribute__((section(".ARM.__at_0x1FE2C"))) = 0xAE20;
```

> Program Size: Code=116924 RO-data=11356 RW-data=1536 ZI-data=14808
> End of bin file with last example:
> [image: end of bin image]

When seeing bin content it seems like CRC could be placed in original location, also there is more free space after CRC. So even program is on limit of not fitting in, it should fit. Question why Keil fails to link it and how I could fit it in?

compiler:

> ArmClang.exe --version
>
> Product: MDK-ARM Cortex-M0/M0+/M23 5.36
>
> Component: ARM Compiler 6.16
>
> Tool: armclang [5dfeb700]
>
> Target: unspecified-arm-none-unspecified

Comment: Is this compiler a GCC based one? If so, did you look into the linker script? Did you generate a map file, perhaps the desired location is not mapped or already used? -- BTW, the address in your code and the address of the dump do not match.

Comment: This is Keil ARM compiler. As for address mismatch - forgot to mention, that start of bin is at 0x200 address, this is due to bootloader vector table being stored in 1st 0x200.

Comment: OK. So the address 0x1FE00 is 127 KiB after 0x200. Is it possible that the memory map of the linker covers all this space, or fills the last allocated block for alignment reasons, and allows you only to use addresses beginning with 0x1FE00? You could do some experiments with different addresses...

Comment: Concerning the compiler, would you mind to run the compiler with just the option "--version", please? According to some quick web research, Keil delivers a GCC for ARM. Newer versions seem to use LLVM/Clang as base.

Comment: As for alignment I would think more in sense of some sort of padding, but it does not seem to correspond with some alignment. Because you need to push CRC further back with each code increase and increment is same. Its like Keil wants to fill these 270-ish bytes with 0xFF. But only if CRC is at the end. Tried moving CRC to start of image, no padding placed after it, and code can go all way to end of flash (this was tested with CRC totally at the end of flash, and application failing to fit in flash - moving CRC to start - solved that issue).

Comment: You might want to add these information right into your question by [edit]ing it. -- Your next steps would be to generate a map file, investigate it, look for some kind of linker script, if you don't provide your own, and investigate that. Put results, please, into the question as addition.

Answer (score 2):

I've just switched to the V6.19 MDK-ARM compiler with Keil uVision and had the same problem when compiling for the STM32L03xx controller.

The version number is placed at the highest addresses of the R/O memory space.

```
#define MAJOR_VERSION   1
#define MINOR_VERSION   2
#define BUILD_VERSION   7

const uint8_t  version_maj __attribute__((used)) __attribute__((section(".ARM.__at_0x08007FF0")))   = MAJOR_VERSION;
const uint8_t  version_min __attribute__((used)) __attribute__((section(".ARM.__at_0x08007FF4")))   = MINOR_VERSION;
const uint16_t version_bld __attribute__((used)) __attribute__((section(".ARM.__at_0x08007FF8")))   = BUILD_VERSION;
```

I also had to free up the last few bytes by limiting the size of the R/O memory, pic below:
[project->options->Target](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h3QfF.png)